# Proof space is Connected Space

Tags: metric-spaces, connectedness, path-connected

Let $A:=\{(0,y):y\in[-1,1]\}$ and $B:=\{(x, sin({1\over x}):x \in (0,1]\}$, finally, let $C:=A\cup B$

1. Show C is a connected space
2. Show C is not path-connected

1 has me stumped,  I have only ever proven that a space is *not* connected.

2 Is duplicate, look here [[proof that topologist sine curve is not locally connected](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1315049/proof-that-topologist-sine-curve-is-not-locally-connected])

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate.  The referenced problem does not address part $1$ of this question.